# Read cookies from Angular to ASP.NET Core 5 app

Tags: c#, angular

I'm trying to read cookie created by Angular app in my ASP.NET Core app. But when I access the cookies from `HttpContext` I couldn't find it.

C#

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["test"]; // always string[0]

services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
  });
```

Angular

```
setCookie() { this.cookieService.set('test', 'test', 36000000, '/', 'localhost'); }
```

The client side works very well because I can see the cookie is settled, also the server-side workers because with in the flutter app after adding the domain name it can be accessed.

Can anyone help me?

[cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj0Kz.png)

Comment: Please post cookieService code. This is not enough information.

Comment: CookieService from ngx-cookie-service

Comment: And what happens if you just set it as per the demo code? `this.cookieService.set('test', 'test')` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1lrgdt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: same problem ! :/

Comment: this works well with the flutter app after adding the domain name